# Making Spigot from FTP Work with my Computer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-spigot

Since I had problems installing Spigot from Buildtools, I decided to open a server on a free hosting website and grab the Spigot files from there. Now all of the Spigot files are on my hard drive.

I tried to open spigot.jar, but it won't open.

I would like to open the spigot.jar file and run it successfully on a Minecraft server. Is this possible using the method above?

Comment: You need to run the spigot jar from the comandline

Comment: Why was this flagged as off-topic?

Comment: @Joachim because I believed it to be tech support for modded minecraft.

Comment: @pppery I don't see it as technical support, rather asking for a specific step in setting up a server: "how do I run the spigot.jar file on my Spigot server?". The question is kind of vague, however.

Answer (score 3):

The spigot website has an excellent tutorial on this: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/spigot-installation/#installation

For short it says you need to make a file ending .bat containing:

```
java -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar spigot.jar nogui
pause
```

in the folder where the spigot.jar is

Then run that file instead of the spigot.jar.

Comment: That link looks like a reasonable answer, but we usually encourage people to avoid external answers. If that site ever goes down, your answer will become useless, If possible it would be great if you could include a decent summery of that links contents here in your answer. (I expect this is the reason for your downvotes)

Comment: Added a summary for the site

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work so well... The .bat file gets executed but after that the command line immediatly closes.  Just like when I open the spigot.jar, it loads for a bit then it won't respond.

Answer (score -5):

you can't open spigot.jar just like you can't open a mod .jar file. you would just put the spigot.jar into ur server file and run server i belive.